# Rotating an array by 180° with strides in C

Tags: c, arrays

Following my more general previous question : [How to rotate an array by ± 180° in an efficient way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930428/how-to-rotate-an-array-by-%c2%b1-180-in-an-efficient-way)

I would like to know how to use memory views or strides in C to rotate an M×N array by 180° without copying it, just by indices transformations.

The indices mapping is as follow :

```
for (i in [0:M-1], j in [0:N-1]) do
    rotated[i, N-1-j] = array[M-1-i, j]
```

The rotated memory view is to be used later in a convolution product

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate a section of a 1d array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409289/how-to-rotate-a-section-of-a-1d-array-in-c)

Comment: How do you intend to access your rotated array?

Comment: by the cells indices

Comment: (a) You say you want to rotate the array without copying it but show a mapping that copies from `array` to `rotated`. If you want to rotate the array in place, you can swap the first element with the last, the second with the second-to-last, etc. This will have half the memory accesses of copying. (b) Many modern processors have SIMD features which may perform this operation more quickly, so an optimal answer depends on the system you will run on and whether you can use non-standard C code for a solution.

Comment: (c) Many convolutions use a small kernel, or at least a kernel much smaller than your array, and it would be faster to rotate the kernel instead of rotating the data array.

Comment: I'm showing here the logic, I know this copies the array, what I would like to know, is if it is possible to just remap the indices. In my case, I convolve an image by its rotated version to identify the kernel (blind deconvolution), so it's the same anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is there are no memory views or strides in C.

The long answer.

Problem is you basically have a flat chunk of memory.

Imagine the following declaration `int arr[3][6]` this essentially means you have a chunk of memory capable to store 18 integer values, so whenever you do something like `int a = arr[2][3]` it is essentially the same as `int a = ((int*)arr)[2*6 + 3]`. So if you have `int arr[M][N]` you may change it inplace or copy to another array. What memory view does in python probably does it provides you with an implicit function to access your data:

```
#define N 10
#define M 20

int arr[M][N];

inline int at_rotated(int size_t i, size_t j) {
  return arr[M-1-i][N-1-j];
}
```

Which is probably no what you want since it forces you to stick to the specified dimensions and to keep an array "global".

A more generic approach would be.

```c
struct arr_s {
  int(*at)(struct arr_s *arr, size_t, size_t);
  size_t rows;
  size_t cols;
  int *data;
};

int at(struct arr_s *arr, size_t i, size_t j) {
  if (arr->at) return arr->at(arr, i, j);
  return arr->data[i * arr->cols + j];
}

int rotated_at_(struct arr_s *arr, size_t i, size_t j) {
  return arr->data[(arr->rows - 1 - i) * arr->cols + (arr->cols - 1 - j)];
}

struct arr_s rotate(struct arr_s *arr) {
  struct arr_s res = *arr;
  res.at = rotated_at_;
  return res;
}

int main(void) {

  struct arr_s some = {
    .rows = 2,
    .cols = 3,
    .data = (int*)(int[2][3]){ { 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} },
  };

  int a = at(&some, 0, 2);

  struct arr_s rotated = rotate(&some);

  int b = at(&rotated, 0, 2);

  printf("%d %d\n", a, b);

  return 0;
}
```

Problem is this is not going to be fast with all this dispatching and stuff. You may combine the first and the second approach though.